# In Java, when is the {a,b,c,...} array shorthand inappropriate, and why?

Tags: java, arrays, notation

If you're defining a variable, it appears to be perfectly valid to declare/define a variable as follows:

```
    double[][] output = {{0,0},{1,0}};
```

But if you're returning a value, it appears to be invalid to write the following:

```
    public double[] foo(){
      return {0,1,2}
    }
```

I would have thought that internally, both of these would have been performing the same action. Eclipse, at least, disagrees. Does anyone know what the difference is, and where else it can be seen, or why it would be beneficial to accept the former example and reject the latter?

Edit: okay, so it's appropriate when you're initializing, but I don't see any ambiguity... couldn't the JVM interpret the type of variable from the name of the variable (in the case of redefining already initialized variables) or when returning (where the JVM could just look at the return type of the function)? What makes initialization a special case of a rule that would prohibit implicit type? What makes the general rule require explicit type?

Comment: You brought up a good point. I be very interested in looking at the source code of the JVM when it comes to this behavior.

Comment: As others said, the Java creators designed it that way. It is demanded like that in the JLS. If you want to know the reason why, you will have to ask one of them.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's only acceptable during a declaration. You can, however, use `new double[] {0, 1, 2}`.

JLS [§10.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6):

> An array initializer may be specified in a declaration, or as part of
>   an array creation expression.

An array creation expression is the `new double[] { }` syntax.

Comment: "It's only acceptable during a declaration." Why? Why not during a return statement?

Comment: @JohnP Because the language doesn't allow it. As far as I know, there is no good case against it (I guess the compiler might have to do a bit more type inference to ensure the creation is safe).

Comment: @Jeffrey I get John's point though. The behavior should be consistent

Comment: @Jeffrey - is there an alternate way to create an array like Arrays.create(1,2,3) ?

Answer (score 22):

You can use braces notation only at the point of declaration, where compiler can infer the type of array from the declaration type.

To use it anywhere else you need to use [*Array Creation Expression*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10):

```
return new double[] {0,1,2};
```

Comment: "To use it anywhere else you need to use Array Creation Expression". Why? Why can't a return statement use the same notation?

Comment: @JohnP. Because, the Java Language Creator designed it that way. See [JLS Section 10.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6).

Comment: No, I don't think so. If I asked why birds developed feathers instead of fur, saying "because the creator made it that way" would be nowhere near satisfactory, right? I'm more likely to accept Jeffrey's answer purely because you begged.

Comment: @JohnP. Hah! Do you really take that as begging. It doesn't matter which answer you accept. I was just telling to accept the answer so that the answer can be considered solved for future visitor. This is a kind of vote of thanks we as a asker give to answerer. Where does begging come from. And if you take that last word- `please` as begging, then you don't understand the difference between begging, and being *polite*.

Comment: @JohnP. However, what kind of answer do you expect me to give you. How can I comment on the decision taken by the language creator, as to why they created it that way. Your reasoning is totally absurd. Still I've tried my best to explain the reason in my answer, if you read it carefully. Read the first line that says, *compiler can infer the type of array from the LHS of assignment*. It can't do that while method invocation or any other place apart from assignment for that matter.

Comment: @JohnP. Further than that, I don't think I or anyone else have the authority to reason more appropriately about this decision.

Comment: I was looking for the reasoning behind the language design. See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/intro-141325.html section 1.2.1, last paragraph. C++ allows you to return a brace initializer since the type is already specified by the signature; Java should not only be able to do the same, but should be motivated to by the reasoning in my link (unless a technical reason prevents it, etc.)


As for the 'begging', I reacted poorly 'accept *my* answer' rather than '*an* answer'. I'd like to apologize for it, two years late and all.

Comment: @JohnP How does one submit a change to the Java  platform for this kind of behavior? I don't change the syntax rule because that would break a lot of code but it be changed to accept both syntaxes and I think it should to be consistent with C++ as you mentioned

Comment: @RohitJain what does LHS stand for? And I'am curious who would have the authority to reason about the decision

Comment: @RohitJain - is there an alternate way to create an array like Arrays.create(1,2,3) ?

Comment: @JohnP and others here:  I would guess the reason you can only do it at creation time is that inference anywhere elsewhere has the potential to be ambiguous and surprising at inopportune times. For example given `Object[] x; x = { 0 };` normal Java most-specific type inference would create `Integer[]` but that could cause a run-time `ArrayStoreException` e.g. if the next line is `x[0] = ""`.

Answer (score 0):

For whose still struggled like @committedandroider:
Declaration and assignment are different things:

```
int[] arr = {1, 2, 3}; // This is valid [declaration]
arr = {2, 3, 4}  // This is invalid! [assignment]
```

Comment: only way to use curly braces syntax while assigning is `arr = new int[] {2,3,4}` like @Jeffrey mentioned

Answer (score -1):

One more edge case I found was in the creation of a two dimensional array and initializing the arrays in the two dimensional array

So from Jeffrey's response - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6  - "An array initializer may be specified in a declaration, or as part of an array creation expression", the below code should appear to work because the the array initializer is being used to initialize the array

```
int[][] grid = new int[3][3];
grid[0] =  {1,1,1};
```

However this didn't work(compilation error), and I had to rewrite this as

```
grid[0] =  new int[]{1,1,1};
```