# Adding integer array as the variable for class

Tags: java, arrays, class

I'm writing a simple Java code for competitors of some random competition. I am adding variables such as age, category, and scores. If I add integers or Strings, there is no problem, but when wanting to add int array (it works when instantiating it and write into the constructor) as an argument to the class, it does not work and thins about the array as 5 discrete integers.
What am I doing wrong?

```
private int [] danceScores = new int[5]; //instance variable

public Competitor(int CNumber, String cName, String cLevel, String dStyle, int[] cScores){                          
    ...;
    danceScores = cScores;}

// in Main method
Competitor competitor1= new Competitor(1, "name", "level", "dance", {1,2,3,4,5});
```

Comment: This question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17933881/7470253).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing integer array is not formatted.
Syntax is wrong here.

It should be like below

```
Competitor competitor1= new Competitor(1, "name", "level", "dance", new int[] {1,2,3,4,5});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass it like this

```
Competitor competitor1= new Competitor(1, "name", "level", "dance", new int[]{1,2,3,4,5});
```

Answer (score 0):

The above constructor call should have given compilation error stating "Array initializer is not allowed here". Add `new int[]`

`Competitor competitor1= new Competitor(1, "name", "level", "dance", new int[] {1,2,3,4,5});`